# How can i pass the object value to .on in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

I have a button, when use click it, it's add two drop down lists, value of second one depend on what user select from first one(values comes from Database),and he can add many drop down lists as he want, So i need to identify each on user selected,
So i do that:
when he click button add

```
    var Incremental = 0;
    $("#add-newProduct").on("click", function () {
        Incremental++;
        LoadCategories();
        var htmlString = `  
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="category-DropDownList`+ Incremental +`"> </select>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <select class="product-DropDownList`+ Incremental +`"></select>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input id="product-price`+ Incremental +`" type="text" disabled />
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input id="product-quantity`+ Incremental +`" type="text" disabled />
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <a class="delete-button`+ Incremental +` button is-danger">remove product</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        `;
        $("#product-rows").append(htmlString);
    });
   

function LoadCategories() {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAllCategories", "Categories")', function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $(".category-DropDownList" + Incremental).html("");
            $(".category-DropDownList" + Incremental).append("<option value=''>no thing selected</option>");
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                $(".category-DropDownList" + Incremental).append("<option value=" + result[i].ID + ">" + result[i].Name + "</option");
            }
        });
```

then when he select a value from .category-DropDownList

```
$("#product-rows").on("change", ".category-DropDownList" + Incremental, function () {
            showProducts($(this).val());
        });
        function showProducts(val)
        {
            console.log(val);
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProductsByCategoryId", "Products")' + "/" + val, function (result) {
                $(".product-DropDownList" + Incremental).html("");
                var data = result;
                console.log(data);
                $(".product-DropDownList" + Incremental).append("<option value=''>no thing selected</option>");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $(".product-DropDownList" + Incremental).append("<option value=" + data[i].ID + ">" + data[i].Name + "</option");
                }
            });
        }
```

So problem here in : $("#product-rows").on("change", ".category-DropDownList" + Incremental, function ()
How can i concatenate Incremental value with .category-DropDownList

Comment: I think you don't have to include the + Incremental part, because $(this).val(); selector is enough to select the current element with declared class.

Comment: If i do that, and use add htmlString let's say 5 times, then every time he will try to choose from category drop down list, that will affecting on all product drop down lists.

Comment: to prevent this, use next('.classname'), so it won't affect the other element with the same class. Also, I recommend to add a snippet to your question, so we can test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this using a common class for each of the elements and use the row they occur in to traverse to other elements in the same row

You will run into problems using incrementals when you start deleting rows and having different numbers of rows than increment etc. It is far more trouble than it is worth when you can do things generically across all rows

Simple example that just changes the value of product to same as category since I don't have data to work with for creating  options

```js
$("#product-rows").on("change", ".category-DropDownList", function() {
  const cat = this.value,
    $row = $(this).closest('tr')
  showProducts(cat, $row);
});


function showProducts(cat, $row) {
  // fake ajax 
  Promise.resolve(cat).then(function(res) {
    $row.find('.product-DropDownList').val(res);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="product-rows">
  <tr>
    <td><select class="category-DropDownList">
        <option value="">--- select Cat---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><select class="product-DropDownList">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select class="category-DropDownList">
        <option value="">--- select Cat---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><select class="product-DropDownList">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine, but still a tiny problem, when i click on the button add new product(that add htmlString) all category drop down lists get reset.

Comment: solve it using .last() XD
thanks for helping
i'm new to front-end so i appreciate it

Comment: Yes perfect...what I was going to suggest

Comment: Note this pattern is very common for working with repeating groups of elements....look up to parent container instance...find within that instance